# ¿Por qué al agregar información a una variable, esta se superpone?

Tags: bash

Quiero traer el resultado de una sesión ssh a una variable local

```
FILEBACK=$(sshpass -p 'pass' ssh admin@1.1.1.1 -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ':put $rvar;')
```

al ver la variable el resultado es el correcto:

```
$ echo "$FILEBACK"
HOLA_COMO
```

Pero si quiero agregarle una extensión a ese valor, se sobrepone al principio:

```
$ echo "$FILEBACK.estas"
.estasOMO
```

el ".estas" se coloca sobre la parte de la variable "HOLA_C" y se muestra el resto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que la cadena que coges tiene un retorno de carro "\r", por lo que cuando añades texto, lo hace a partir del principio de la misma línea:

```
$ printf "hola\rXX\n"
XXla                   # en lugar de "hola", sobrescribe XX encima del principio de "hola"
```

Por tanto, lo que debes hacer es eliminar este carácter de tu cadena:

```
FILEBACK=$(sshpass -p ... | tr -d '\r')
```

En mi ejemplo de antes:

```
$ printf "hola\rXX" | tr -d '\r'
holaXX
```